# Is `app.get("/", func1, func2);` the same as `app.get("/", func1); app.get("/", func2);`?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to make a routing system for my web app in express.js and I need to know if I'm going to need to use app.get/post/put/delete.apply to programmatically setup multiple functions for one route.

So is

```
app.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
    code();
    next();
});

app.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
    finish();
});
```

the same as

```
app.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
    code();
    next();
}, function(req, res, next) {
    finish();
});
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's pretty much the same.

If possible, you can 'promote' the setup function to a proper middleware by using `app.use`:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  code();
  next();
});
```

But that would only useful if it needs to be run for *all* your routes.

Or, if you want to reuse it for *some* routes, you can do something like this:

```
var MyMiddleware = function(req, res, next) {
  code();
  next();
});

app.get("/", MyMiddleware, function(req, res) {
  finish();
});
```